# sqlite - combine same field in 2 rows into 2 columns based on field value

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions

I have a sqlite table with data similar to the following:

```
 id | flag
----+-----
  1 |  0
  2 |  0
  3 |  1
  4 |  0
  5 |  1
  6 |  0
  7  | 1
```

I'd like to get results that look like the following:

```
id1 | id2
----+-----
  1 | null
  2 | null
  3 |   5
  4 | null
  6 | null
  7 | null
```

To explain, I'm trying to "combine" the id's of each "pair" of records (in order) where "flag == 1". Where the record has "flag == 0", id2 should just be NULL. Also notice, since I have a odd number of records where "flag == 1" (in this example), the final one (id = 7) doesn't have an additional record to pair with, so it too has an id2 field of NULL.

Is this possible via pure SQL (sqlite3 in this case)? I can obviously post-process the results in the host application, but was hoping to not have to.

*** EDIT ***

Adding the requested MRE...

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    flag INTEGER NOT NULL );
 
INSERT INTO test(flag) VALUES(0),(0),(1),(0),(1),(0),(1);
```

Comment: Surely possible. Please provide a MRE as described in the tag wiki you used https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info to make answering easier.

Comment: Thanks. MRE added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with window functions `MIN()` and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT id id1, CASE WHEN flag THEN next END id2 
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY flag ORDER BY id) rn,
         MIN(CASE WHEN flag THEN id END) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) next
  FROM test
)
WHERE flag = 0 OR rn % 2 = 1
ORDER BY id1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5dd41cdea3da2e151be0672d4d729c30).
Results:

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | null |
| 6 | null |
| 7 | null |

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self join along with `SUM()` window function increasing as id value increases while distinguishing odd and even values through use of modulus operator(`%`) such as

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS fl 
   FROM test
)   
SELECT t1.id AS id1, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.flag * t2.flag* abs(t2.fl % 2-1)=1 THEN t2.id END ) AS id2
  FROM t AS t1
  LEFT JOIN t AS t2
    ON t1.fl + 1 = t2.fl 
 GROUP BY t1.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c5f1562d389a64d14e5b38c8d7495586)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. However, looking at the linked demo, this doesn't produce the expected results. When an item is "paired" into the 2nd column (id2), it should no longer appear elsewhere in the result set (see my original sample output). 

In your Demo, for instance, I see `3 | 5` correctly paired together, but then later see `5 | null` in the result set.

Comment: You're welcome @JeffGodfrey , but I've just expanded the data in order to show more pairs. For the original case delete the last two records [such as](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=443cd1887dea3d58a2dffef0ee772e1e)

Comment: Hi Barbaros. I don't think that's the issue. A single record ID should not appear more than once in the result set. Regardless of whether the additional records are included or not, I see record ID `5` twice in the result set. Once, paired with record 3 and once by itself.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something?